# How to use IntroJS in angular project

Tags: angular, intro.js

I have purchased license of IntroJs for our commerical application. I would like to know how i can integrate the source code provided by IntroJs into Angular Application. There is no were it is provided that how we can integrate the source code provided by introJs.